# How to deal with not matching XPath expression result in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I wrote the following line to parse images from twitter profiles and it works most of the time except that this line kills it's containing script when the page doesn't contain a match.

I'm more familiar with regex parsing but thought I would try something new and learn the xpath process but I'm not sure what I'm missing?  I've tried try/catch logic and that didn't help.  How can I prevent this xpath query from stopping the script and just return '' if no match is found?

```
$img = '';
$img = @$xpath->query("//*[@class='profile-img' or @id='profile-image']" )->item( 0 )->getAttribute( 'src' );
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try not inlining the access of the results.  Store the `query()` result, check it for content, then look at `->item(0)->getAttribute('src')`

Comment: @user603424: This is not about XPath but null objects references in PHP. Retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hadn't suppressed the error with `@` this would be immediately clear.  If no results are returned by `query`, calling `item(0)` will return `NULL`. Calling `getAttribute` on `NULL` will obviously fail badly.

You should check the length:

```
$img = $xpath->query("//*[@class='profile-img' or @id='profile-image']")->item(0);
$img = $img ? $img->getAttribute('src') : '';
```

This uses a ternary statement: if `$img` is not null, it will return the `src` attribute. Otherwise it will return an empty string.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  yeah, it was driving me crazy why no error message was being generated.  Thanks!

Comment: @user Moral of the story: don't use the error suppression operator!